# Apply a style to an entire Excel sheet with the R package openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I'm utilizing an R package named *openxlsx*. I've created the `AlignStyle` seen below. I want to apply this style to the entire sheet titled 'test-sheet'. When I try to apply this style to all rows and all columns of the Excel sheet I get an `Error in 1:Inf : result would be too long a vector`.

```
# Define a style
AlignStyle <- createStyle(halign = "CENTER", valign = "TOP")

# Apply the style
addStyle(wb, "test-sheet", style = AlignStyle, rows = 1:Inf, cols = 1:Inf, gridExpand = TRUE)
```

I know I could do something like `rows = 1:nrows(df)` but the name of my dataframe won't always be `df`.

Do you know of another way I can apply a style to an entire sheet, or an entire workbook, with the *openxlsx* R package?

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be `Inf` and not some arbitrarily large number, such as excel's row limit (1,048,576, according to Google)?

Comment: I did try that, first on a smaller scale (50K rows and 200 columns). It took several minutes to render the `.xlsx` file and it was over 30 MB in size. There were only about 100 populated cells in this spreadsheet. I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
map(df, ~addStyle(wb, "test-sheet", style = AlignStyle, rows = 0:nrow(.x)+1, cols = 0:ncol(.x)+1, gridExpand = TRUE)
```

Adding the +1 at the end will include all every cell if the first row is the header